# Simple partial derivative of function with summation - how to solve it?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need some help with the computation of a partial derivative.
The function is

$$f(x) = \sum_{a=1}^A x_a \bigg(\sum_{b=1}^{a-1} x_b^2 + \delta\bigg)^{-\gamma}$$

I need to compute the partial derivative of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_a}$, but I am not sure how to deal with the summation.

Comment: Here $a$ is the sum's index. So it doesn't make sense to compute the partial derivative wrt $x_a$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am a bit confused. What would be the derivative of $f(x) = x (\sum_{b=1}^{a-1} x_b^2 + \delta)^{-\gamma}$ ? Is it right to say that it's $\frac{1}{(\sum_{b=1}^{a-1} x_b^2 + \delta)^{\gamma}}$? I have a hard time understanding how to deal with the summation.

Comment: All the $x_b$ terms in the second sum are different from any $x_a$ in the first sum (because the sum goes up to $a-1$). Try to write $f(x)$ explicitly for say $A = 3$, then take the partial derivatives for $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.

Comment: Thank you, now it's more clear!